# In PowerBI DAX, trying to capture greatest fiscal month user has filtered on

Tags: filter, dax, fiscal

In my PowerBI, the user can filter on fiscal years and fiscal months.  In a custom column, I need to capture the fiscal period number of the greatest fiscal month that the user has filtered on.  For example, if the user selects fiscal year 2019 and fiscal months April through October, in the custom column I need 201907 (my fiscal year runs April to March, so October is 07).  I have tried variations of this

```
FilteredFP = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Dates[FiscalPeriod])
)
```

But the result is always all seven fiscal periods (201901, 201902, ...).  Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer since it's not clear what you want to do. If you want a calculated column (CC) then I would suggest a different approach. A CC is only refeshed/recalculated when the entire table is refreshed, and will not be refreshed simply by changing a slicer. If it's a measure you're trying to create then a description of the different tables and relationships in your model is needed for us to be able to help you efficiently. Please have a look at this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For usability, the report user is selecting a fiscal year and fiscal month name on my filters page.  I need to take that filter data and equate to the greatest fiscal period selected.  Fiscal period (in the format YYYYMM) is another column in the same Dates table that contains the years and months.  I need the fiscal period to do further calculations.  Hopefully that clarifies a bit more.  Thank you.

Comment: Never mind.  MAX(Dates[FiscalPeriod]) worked when used in a measure instead of a column.  Thanks!